# Dot Net Nuke (DNN) 4.9.x Subscription Module

Tags: paypal, dotnetnuke, paypal-subscriptions, subscriptions

I required a module which can manage subscriptions in Dot Net Nuke.

A Subscription will be used to allow access to website.

It needs to be able to do the following

- Use PayPal for recurring payments
- Activate Subscription on payment
- Deactivate Subscription on payment cancelled
- Subscription on a yearly basis

Any recommendations would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: DNN Subscription Module, http://www.codingstaff.com/products/dotnetnuke-modules/dnn-subscription

> Looking to create a subscription-based
>   portal? There is a hassle free
>   solution by Coding Staff - DNN
>   Subscription module. Combined with
>   DotNetNuke® CMS this module will help
>   to create the subscription-based
>   portal with user accounts, roles and
>   online content accessible only by
>   subscribers.
>
> With PayPal DNN Subscription module by
>   Coding Staff  you don't have to be a
>   programmer or a web guru to set up a
>   subscription-based portal. With this
>   module you can subscribe your clients
>   to existing services you provide or to
>   some portion of your website. Use DNN
>   Subscriptions to bill customers on a
>   regular basis, charge membership dues,
>   or offer subscription services and
>   installment payment plans.
>
> The ability to combine the portal user
>   roles and registration with DNN
>   subscription module allows to show
>   some sections of your website only to
>   subscribers. Moreover, you can have
>   various subscription plans  and
>   settings.